# Multithreaded Round Robin Tournament

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to test 8 different game-playing algorithms. These algorithms can play against each other different type of games that follow an Game interface.

So, they have to play against each other 100 games. I've done that part and it works fine. Now, I'm trying to make it multithreaded, to take advantage of the 8-cores of a computer of a friend.

I have very little experience working with threads. So, what kind of changes would I have to make in order to make my code multithreaded?

Here is the code for my single threaded version.

EDIT: The solution I thought of (with my basic knowledge) is about making a Match class, which takes two players and the game they want to play. That class would implement Runnable and I could make a thread for each of the games. My question now would be, how would I notify of the results once the run() method is finished?

Thanks

```
for (int p1 = 0; p1 < allPlayers.length; p1++)
{
    for (int p2 = p1 + 1; p2 < allPlayers.length; p2++)
    {    
        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
        {
            int player1 = t % 2 == 0 ? p1 : p2;
            int player2 = t % 2 == 0 ? p2 : p1;
            Player[] players = new Player[] { allPlayers[player1], allPlayers[player2] };
            game.newGame();

            while (!game.isFinished())
                game.playNthMove(players[game.currentPlayer()].move(game));

            data[p1][p2][t] = getCharValue(game.getOutcome()[t % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1]);
            data[p2][p1][t] = getCharValue(game.getOutcome()[t % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Collection<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>();
for (int p1 = 0; p1 < allPlayers.length; p1++)
{
    for (int p2 = p1 + 1; p2 < allPlayers.length; p2++)
    {    
        for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
        {
            final int player1 = t % 2 == 0 ? p1 : p2;
            final int player2 = t % 2 == 0 ? p2 : p1;
            final Player[] players = new Player[] { allPlayers[player1], allPlayers[player2] };
            final int trial = t;
            tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
               public Void call() {
                 game.newGame();

                 while (!game.isFinished())
                    game.playNthMove(players[game.currentPlayer()].move(game));

                 data[p1][p2][t] = getCharValue(game.getOutcome()[t % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1]);
                 data[p2][p1][t] = getCharValue(game.getOutcome()[t % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0]);
                 return null;
              }
           });
        }
    }
}
executor.invokeAll(tasks); // called on an exector, will wait for all tasks to complete
```

The problem with the current design is that the game object does not look thread safe.  You'll probably want a new game object for each Runnable.

Answer (score 3):

You  shouldn't need to modify the code for the single-threaded implementation - you should just need to make a class that implements the Runnable interface and wrap that functionality in a run() method. Then you can make a Thread passing in an instance of that class, and call `Thread.start()`.

See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) for a reference.

**Edit:** How to get results from that thread:

It looks like the Callable Interface is what you're looking for. Here's a [link](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6) with a basic explanation on how to use it. It requires a basic knowledge of how the Runnable interface is used for creating a multi-threaded application without results, so I'd recommend reading [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) first.

Comment: So, should I need something like a Match class, where I pass the two players and the game they want to play, and that class should implement the runnable interface lets say? Then, what would happen when the game is over? How do I notify the results?

Comment: @wanstein Honestly, I've never worked with multi-threaded applications in Java - though I have a fair amount of experience with them in C#. From that perspective, yes, I'd start with making a class implementing `Runnable` that gets passes the two players and the game they want to play, and can run a game.

Comment: @wanstein As far as how to get results, in C# my first instinct would be to fire an event on the main thread with the results passed as and EventArg. I don't think that's how Java works, though. After some googling, I found this [link](http://blogs.sun.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6), which explains how to use Callable to return values from another thread, and includes a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

There is not magic bullet. You need to know the basics before asking that question. Start by reading this article at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx. It's pretty much the same for Java.

When done, come back and ask another question regarding a problem you got with your own attempt.

Sure, you might get another answer here showing you what to do. But ***please***, do not read that answer. It's vital that you understand the basics before going further. Otherwise you'll be completely lost when your app stops working.

Comment: I have no problems with down votes. But ***please*** explain why so that I can learn from them.

Comment: Well, I wasn't expecting a complete solution at all. I was expecting someone to tell me something like: use a Thread per Match, use an Executor, use a Thread Pool, etc. I was expecting more like an idea of the possible solution, where to start, not the coded solution.

Comment: I edited the question to give an idea of what I was planning to do. Better?

Comment: I've warned you. It's up to you if you want to listen or not. As for notification, just add a simple event which is invoked when the `Match ` thread have completed. You can use `thread.Join` to wait on running threads/matches.